# Does it make sense to replace sub-queries by join?

Tags: mysql, optimization, select, join, subquery

For example I have a query like that.

```
select col1 from t1 where col2>0 and col1 in (select col1 from t2 where col2>0)
```

As far as I understand, I can replace it by the following query:

```
select t1.col1 from t1
join (select col1 from t2 where col2>0) as t2
on t1.col1=t2.col1
where t1.col2>0
```

**ADDED**

In some answers I see `join` in other `inner join`. Are both right? Or they are even identical?

Comment: I don't know about MySQL... But I'm pretty sure a `JOIN` *tends* to be faster in SQL Server and Oracle.

Comment: Your join here is still using a sub-query, thus not rendering it faster.

Comment: As far as JOIN types go, from memory, I think JOIN is equivalent to INNER JOIN also have a look here http://www.wellho.net/mouth/158_MySQL-LEFT-JOIN-and-RIGHT-JOIN-INNER-JOIN-and-OUTER-JOIN.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470991/what-query-will-be-the-fastest/4472966#4472966

Answer (score 2):

A join is usually faster, but the best way to decide is to benchmark.

Comment: +1: the only person to provide an explanation of the 2 relevant reasons!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
select col1 from t1 
inner join t2 ON t2.col1 = t1.col1
where t1.col2>0 and t2.col2>0
```

A JOIN is definitely the way to go here

Answer (score 1):

Even better:

```
select t1.col1
    from t1
        inner join t2
            on t1.col1 = t2.col1
    where t1.col2>0
        and t2.col2>0
```

Answer (score 1):

actually this is sufficient

```
select t1.col1 
from t1 join t2 On t2.col1 = t1.col1
Where t1.col2 > 0
   and t2.col2 > 0
```

As to which is faster,  the only way to be sure is to test.  But I would suggest that unless performance is a real user-experience issue, the more important issue is long-term maintainability, for which the clarity of the SQL is a prime factor.  And the sub-query approach, to my mind, expresses the function you are implementing more clearly

Answer (score 1):

With such a Problem you should go for a join in any case

```
select t1.col1 
from t1 join t2 On t1.col1 = t2.col1
where t1.col2 > 0 and t2.col2 > 0
```

and there is no difference between "join" and "inner join". The "inner" can be omitted because its the default; only the "outer" with its type has to be specified. However, the "join" can be omitted too if you write it like this:

```
select t1.col1 
from t1, t2 
where t1.col2 > 0 and t2.col2 > 0 
  and t1.col1 = t2.col1
```

Comment: `outer` does not have to be specified.  outer joins come in several types, `Left outer`, `right outer`, `full outer`, and the `left`, `right` or `full` IS required, but the keyword `outer`, just like the keyword `inner`, is optional.   The second construction ("omitting the keyword Join")  is a totally different construction from Ansi-Standard SQL-89, and should not be used.

Comment: You're right, what I meant was, that you have to specify the type of outer, not the word outer, which can be omitted in most of the DBMSs. I'm not agree, that the second construction should not be used, because there still exist DBMS that don't support the first join construction. As far as I know internally the optimizers construct the same query out of both types, only that the first should be used because it is clearer what happens

Answer (score 1):

What makes sense depends on your coding standards.

I would avoid benchmarking sub-queries vs joins until the query itself has been optimized (removing extraneous joins, tautologous where clauses, excessive column retrieval) AND profiling demonstrates the need to optimize a particular query.

Even then, your time is probably better spent on defining good indexes for the RDBMS to use during execution.

Answer (score 0):

And how about something like this:

`select t1.col1 
from t1 join t2 On t2.col1 = t1.col1

    AND  t1.col2 > 0`

Answer (score 0):

In many cases the query optimiser will rewrite your sub-queries as joins. If your sub-query is one of them, rewriting it will be a waste of time. How to tell if that is the case, though, I don't know. If your current query is a problem, the EXPLAIN command will probably help you out.